# postman-to-k6 sends request twice

Tags: postman, grafana, load-testing, k6

I use postman-to-k6 to convert my postman collection to a k6 script.  When the k6 script is run, there is 50% http_req_failed.

I realized that if it sends request to "temp. com/login", it also sends request to "temp. com/". Since there is no endpoint like "temp. com/", there is failure. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does your generated k6 script contain 2 requests? Did your postman contain 2 requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want any redirection, you can set the maxRedirects option to 0, so that k6 doesn’t follow HTTP redirects automatically.

```
export const options = {
   maxRedirects: 0,
}
```

Another thing to mention is, `http_req_failed` means that request returned 4XX or 5XX error. So, if one of your requests return any status from these series, it will be treated as a failed request and will result 50% http request failure at the end of the test. If you want to handle the redirection request metrics explicitly you can try handling them with [custom metrics](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/metrics/#custom-metrics).